# Sash paint brushes are designed to achieve a fine finish on "profile" surfaces and detail work

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "profile" mean in "[Sash paint brushes are designed to achieve a fine finish on profile surfaces and detail work](https://paintersworld.co.uk/products/brushes/sash-brushes)"? Does it mean "an outline of an object" in this context? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It means surfaces with lots of relief or contour, like door frames, window frames and [coving](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&iar=images&q=coving&iax=images&ia=images). It does not mean outline.